# How to set HTTP headers for 404 Not found pages with Rails/Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, x-frame-options

I need to set the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header for pages that return `404 - Not Found` in my rails app but I can't figure out how to do it. I am not able to set these headers using rails, I found one possible reason [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20903). However, I don't know how I could set them with the Webserver either, I'm using Puma.

I don't actually have anything that can be `ClickJacked` in my `404 - not found` pages but an external security org still requires me to do so.

Comment: Can this guide help you? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/security.html#default-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails the exceptions are handled by `config.exceptions_app`. The default app just renders the static html files from the public directory but this can be any rack compliant application.

The most basic example of a Rack compliant application is:

```
app = ->(env){  [ 404, { "Content-Type" => "text/plain", "X-Frame-Options" => "some value" }, ["Oh no I cant find it!"] ] }
```

It takes one argument (A hash) and returns an array(status, headers, body).

Both the Rails routes and `ActionController::Metal` (and thus all your controllers) are rack compliant applications and even `config/application.rb`. In fact Rails is just a russian doll scheme of Rack apps.

If you want to handle this through your routes you can do:

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/404', to: "errors#not_found"
get '/422', to: "errors#unprocessable_entity"
get '/500', to: "errors#internal_error"
```

```
class ErrorsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action do
    response.set_header('X-Frame-Options', 'HEADER VALUE')
  end

  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render file: Rails.root.join('public', '404.html'), layout: false, status: :not_found }
    end
  end

  def unprocessable_entity 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render file: Rails.root.join('public', '422.html'), layout: false, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

  def internal_error
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render file: Rails.root.join('public', '500.html'), layout: false, status: :internal_server_error }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you won't see any changes in  development unless you set config.consider_all_requests_local to false. That's what makes rails serve those developer friendly error pages in dev.